# Can't find/delete installed application

Tags: uninstall, locate, desktop-apps

I am going mad as I can't find a *WhatsApp* package that I want to uninstall. It apparently is not installed with *snap*, can't be located using `grep`, `dpkg`, `which`, and the path identified in the process menu doesn't exist.

Here is a screenshot of the process overview. Only the *WhatsApp* version I'd like to uninstall is running.

[image]

Other than that the app works fine, I just want to use another one that loads faster. The logo is the normal *WhatsApp* one.

I have some similar problems with different ubuntu-versions of the same applications which I would like to uninstall. Where are they saved?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: The path `/app/bin/` in your image suggests Flatpak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not install the package using a package manager - by default either traditional APT and snap on Ubuntu, then you are the only person on earth that can tell us how you installed it. How you can remove a manually installed app depends on how it has been installed. Since you tell you are planning to install "a version that loads faster", you seem to know what you are doing. We cannot.

The path listed in the command line that runs the application indeed suggests this is an application that does not follow the distribution's standard. It shows that the command to run the package is the shell, "sh", followed by a file name `/bin/sh /app/bin/whatsapp-desktop-linux`, which, in order to be run with `sh`, must be a shell script. `/app` is not at all a conventional directory to store manually installed applications. Typically, such applications are installed under `/opt`.

With respect to "similar versions", that only can happen indeed when manually installing applications, or when installing an application both using APT and snap.